# Snort can’t start and says it failed to parse the IP address: 8.0.0.0/8.0.0.0

Tags: windows, windows-10, snort

I need to use Snort in Windows.

I've done the configuration several times but no luck. Snort always returns  output like this

[image: Snort errors.]

The Snort configuration file [can be found here on Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fIwQmEm-H0c-mVVx6dmpN35I_nIxCE27/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Is that supposed to be `address/netmask`?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the relevant parts of your config file.

Comment: @DavidPostill sorry, i don't know which part of the config file is relevant for the problem :(

Comment: I have found the problem, you must disable all the interface. except the one that connect to the internet. thanks all.

Comment: Please don’t post screenshots of text from the command line; it’s hard to read and hard to search. Just copy and paste the text and post it in your answer. That is easier to read.

Comment: Look at [this similar issue](https://seclists.org/snort/2018/q4/360).